# HashMap bucket is unused when we have Link list of Entry object which same HashCode and Difference Equals

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Person class whose hashCode will always return same int value e.g. 101 and equals always return false i.e.

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 101;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;
    }
```

Now, I have put 100 Person object in a HashMap i.e.

```
Map<Person, Integer> personMap = new HashMap<Person, Integer>();
        for(int i = 1; i<=100; i++){
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setId(i);
            personMap.put(p, i);
        }
```

HashMap put method will create the Entry object everytime, since the hashCode is same for all the Person object and equals return false, Entry will maintain the Linked List of similar HashCode, but with that we have a increase in HashMap **size** with the **bucket size**. Now I am wondering why we are increasing the HashMap size and bucket when Entry itself is maintaining the Linked List?

Seeking for example and explaination which justify why HashMap need to do so.

Comment: Side note. Your `equals` method violate its contract. `a.equals(a)` must return `true`.

Comment: This is just an example to undestand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

We are increasing the `HashMap` capacity to maintain a low average number of Entries per bucket, which allows us to `put` and `get` entries to/from the `HashMap` in expected constant time (i.e O(1)).

Your example is a bad usage of `HashMap`, since you force all the entries into the same bucket, but in normal use cases, most buckets will have 0 or 1 entries, and few buckets will have more than 1 (assuming a low load factor is used).

The number of buckets in the `HashMap` is increased when the total number of Entries in the `HashMap` reaches `capacity * loadFactor`, where `capacity` is the current number of buckets. Therefore, if `loadFactor < 1` (the default is 0.75), each bucket will contain less than 1 `Entry` on average.

Comment: This is just an example to undestand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

As the number of entries to the Map increases the Load Factor of the map comes into picture to maintain a effective distribution of the keys withing the Map. Remember that the HashMap does NOT know your implementation of the hashcode function and Load Factor works on the effective size of the Map.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` simply not designed for this use case. It assume that hash codes will be randomly distributed.